# What is overlay?

Tags: online, tournament

I have recently started playing more tournaments and have come across the term "overlay" used by online poker rooms. Usually it is described in a dollar amount, like "tournament x had a $500 overlay". not sure exactly what this means, but it only seems to come up in tournaments with a guaranteed prize pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_(poker))

> In poker, an overlay is the gap between a poker tournament's
>   guaranteed prize pool and the actual prize pool generated by entrants.
>
> For example, if a tournament has a guaranteed prize pool of $10,000, a
>   buy in of $100 and 90 players enter, the players will contribute only
>   $9,000 to the prizepool. The rest of the prizepool (in this example
>   $1,000)—made up by the tournament host—would be the overlay for the
>   tournament.